# Serve files directly from server or use database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-applications, filesystems

I'm working on a webapp that works as an access to a set of Office files, and I'm doubtful about how to manage this files in the backend, my backend is a NodeJS application. I was thinking to implement a MongoDB database and use GridFS to store and manage the set of files, but I dont know if this is unnecessary considering that the files don't need to be related in complex manners. The other option is to use the Node Filesystem. I would like to know which one is the right way and why.

Thank you in advance for your help

Edit: The files aren't static and require metadata to be processed.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a right or wrong answer to this question..

Comment: Agreed with @aw04. Are you serving these files statically? Will they change a lot? Do you need to add metadata information around these files to process them in any way?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't asked the question correctly, english is not my native language. Basically I'm asking if there's any inconvenience on serving and storing the set of files directly on my Node server instead of using a database. Edit: yes, my files require some metadata to process them, and no, the files aren't static –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main disadvantage of traditional filesystem in your case is scalability, you wouldn't be able to scale you app in case you need more processing power on multiple servers by relying on filesystem storage.